# How to use page directive value in jsp element?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I wants to use page directive value in jsp element (e.g. value 'i' to be used in textbox with name='hidden'), which will be used to count total number of unsuccessful attempt.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Application </title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
        <%
        Integer i = (Integer)application.getAttribute("i");
        if (i == null) {
            i = new Integer(1);
        } else {
            i = new Integer(i.intValue() + 1);
        }
        application.setAttribute("i", i);

        session.setAttribute("attemp", i); 
        out.println("Attemp :::::"+ session.getAttribute("attemp"));
        %>
<s:form action="login.action" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
    <s:submit method="doGet" key="label.login" align="center" />
    <s:textfield id="hidden" name="hidden" value="<%=i %>" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Scriplet` is outdated
You can avoid scriptlet accessing Application and Session in struts way, don't forget to use **`#`** while accessing **`Application`,`Session`** Or **`Request`** scope variable
Here I have tried to avoid `Scriplet` code, Also please confirm while accessing `Application` variable...
For a help refer https://struts.apache.org/docs/accessing-application-session-request-objects.html

```
<s:if test="%{#application.i == null}">
    <s:set name="i" value="1" scope="application" />
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:set name="i" value="%{#application.i + 1}" scope="application" />
</s:else>

<s:set name="attemp" value="%{#application.i}" scope="session" />
```

And Set Your `hidden` `textfield` as :

```
<s:textfield id="hidden" name="hidden" value="%{#application.i}" />
```